# Error:Attribute "color" has already been defined, update appcompat v-7

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am trying to update my appcompat-v7 in Android Studio project from v20.0.0 to 21.0.0 for use material design component but I allways get the same error:

"Error:Attribute "color" has already been defined"

I have not idea about what to do for fix this error, I searched in internet  but I cant get the answer.
Here is my gradle:

```
android {

    compileOptions.encoding = "iso-8859-1"
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"

}
```

Here is the path where the conflict exist

```
C:\Users\Abel Dominguez\Documents\PROYECTOS_ANDROID\definitivos\d2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\values\values.xml
```

and this is other error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Abel Dominguez\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\build-tools-21.1.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Abel Dominguez\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\platforms\android-21\android.jar -M C:\Users\Abel Dominguez\Documents\PROYECTOS_ANDROID\definitivos\d2\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Abel Dominguez\Documents\PROYECTOS_ANDROID\definitivos\d2\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\Abel Dominguez\Documents\PROYECTOS_ANDROID\definitivos\d2\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\Abel Dominguez\Documents\PROYECTOS_ANDROID\definitivos\d2\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Abel Dominguez\Documents\PROYECTOS_ANDROID\definitivos\d2\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.wherefriend -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Abel Dominguez\Documents\PROYECTOS_ANDROID\definitivos\d2\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    C:\Users\Abel Dominguez\Documents\PROYECTOS_ANDROID\definitivos\d2\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:94: error: Attribute "color" has already been defined
```

Comment: Use compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3' instead of compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My problem was solved after I read the answer by @petey. If you look at the line displayed in error message you can precisely determine which attribute is causing problem.

In my case, it was an attribute named `color` in a custom `attrs` xml file. That custom view wasn't used so I just commented that line and problem was solved.

**Possible solution steps**

1. Check error output to find the path to the file and line number that is causing problems
2. Go to that file through your file system explorer and look for the line in question
3. That line should mention what (custom) view has an attribute that is already defined somewhere.
4. Back in the project in you IDE, find that attribute and if it is not used comment, otherwise if it IS used, change it's name.

Comment: This was exactly the same issue I had. Someone had added the attribute "color" for their custom view. Although the compiler never informed me what line and where the error occurred. Thanks for this!

Comment: Same for me. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It would be nice if the author of the question accepted this answer if it was helpful - @AbelMorgan

Answer (score 3):

You should remove this line

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
```

and use the same dependency used by appcompat:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
```

Also I suggest to fix the 21.0.3 instead of 21.0.+

Comment: Yes, `appcompat-v7:21.0.3` will also add `support-v4:21.0.3` which will conflict with `support-v4:20.0.0`. Always use up-to-date versions of support libraries.

Comment: This does help, but the problem may persist if there are two view attributes with the same name

Answer (score 0):

**Gradle Resource Merger** merges all resource folders from all dependencies and place into single folder. In case there are duplicates build process will fail.

Fortunately, if you look below under Output: label, you will find the right path to the problem.

Here is an example

[image]

in your case it is  `android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values\attrs.xml:476: error: Attribute "attributeName" has already been defined`

You can also build your project from command line and get the right path. attributeName Inside values\attrs.xml file on line 476 you would find a with property named "attributeName". Most probably it is your own styleable that you have to change to get rid of the duplicate.

So now, when you know the reason, you can locate that property in your project module and replace it with different name.

Answer (score 0):

In some case this might help you. This is not a specific answer though.

```
tools:attr markers
```

There can be be many attribute related markers on any particular element to resolve all attributes in conflict.

```
<tools:strict=”x, y, z”>
```

Default implicit mode for attribute, generate an error when trying the merge lower priority attribute declaration with a different value.

```
<tools:remove=”x, y, z”>
```

Remove the x, y, z attributes from any lower priority declaration when merging in.

```
<tools:replace=”x, y, z”>
```

Replace the x, y, z attributes from any lower priority declaration with the provided value (must be present on the same node).

REF: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:attr-markers