# support-v7 Attribute "color" has already been defined

Tags: android-studio

My compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are set to 23. My buildToolsVersion is set to 23.0.2.

The android-support-v7-appcompat is 23 version, but when i run the project, happen the error!

Who can help me?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928196/errorattribute-color-has-already-been-defined-update-appcompat-v-7

Comment: May be a resources name conflict between `app-compat` and other library cause this issue. Try update `app-compat` and other library to latest version.